# draw lines around specific areas in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame  `(df1)` which i generated a `geom_tile` plot from it.

```
X Y Z
1 1 0.343
5 4 0.134
10 6 0.564
20 8 0.532
40 9 0.235
46 12 0.425
```

and i have another data frame which i want to use to draw the lines `(df2)`:

```
a b c     d
1 1 0.05 good
5 4 0.01 better
10 6 0.03 middle
20 8 0.1  bad
40 9 0.2  bad
46 12 0.22 bad
```

so the idea, is that `a` and `X` are the same and `b` and `Y` are the same values.

what i want to do is to draw some lines around the `geom_tile` areas depending on the value of `d` in `df2`. so in each different area there will be a different color line e.g (good is red, better is blue, ...)

i tried to use `geom_contour` but the problem it draws lines in a very ugly way and i wasn't able to specify coordinates in a good way ..

***Note***

- some areas might not be in straight lines
- data frames are bigger, this is a test data to explain the idea

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest, first, to merge both data frame together as they have the same values in two columns.

```
 df.new<-merge(df1,df2,by.x=c("X","Y"),by.y=c("a","b"))
 df.new
   X  Y     Z    c      d
1  1  1 0.343 0.05   good
2 10  6 0.564 0.03 middle
3 20  8 0.532 0.10    bad
4 40  9 0.235 0.20    bad
5 46 12 0.425 0.22    bad
6  5  4 0.134 0.01 better
```

Then in `aes()` set `fill=` for the Z (if necessary) and `color=d`. `size=2` in `geom_tile()` will ensure that lines around tiles are better visible.

```
 ggplot(df.new,aes(X,Y,fill=Z,color=d))+geom_tile(size=2)
```

Similar results can be achieved also without merging data frame - you should use two `geom_tile()` calls (one for each data frame) and in second `geom_tile()` (where color is set) add `fill=NA` outside `aes()`.

```
ggplot()+geom_tile(data=df1,aes(X,Y,fill=Z))+
         geom_tile(data=df2,aes(a,b,color=d),size=2,fill=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but will this work for examle for multiple tiles together ? e.g big group of data which have a good value, will they be treated as one rectangle or square or whatever..besides i think this will not work when we have no straight lines

Comment: since the data frames i have are much bigger as i wrote in the question, the geom_tiles are too small and in some case we have a cluster of geom_tiles which is not straight (rectangele or ...) it can be in weird shapes .. will this draw a line around them all together? or around each geom_tile a different contour ??

Comment: i've tried it, it does for each geom_tile a different contour .. which is not exactly what i want ..

Comment: @ifreak Could add to your question some picture what exactly you want to achieve. If for example five points overlap - should they have the same line around (even if their d values are different)?